# Show that the set of odd functions that are differentiable in the interval [-10, 10] is a vectorial space

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

> Show that
>   $$
> V = \left\{ \left. f \in C^1_{[-10,10]} \right| f \text{ is odd} \right\}
> $$
>   is a vector space.

i only need to show thee axiom of the lock for addition and multiplication

Comment: The "axiom of the lock?"  Anyway, why can't you prove the axioms?  Can you write down what you are supposed to prove?  In this case, that's pretty much the whole battle.

Comment: i don't understand how to do that

Comment: For example, you have to show that if $f$ is odd and $a$ is a scalar, then $af$ is odd.  This is obvious if you know what an odd function is.  If you don't, look in your textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean *closure* not *lock* likely.

Let $f,g \in V$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $af \in V$ and $f+g \in V$.

Comment: Do I have to use the definition of the odd function?

Comment: @ByrionBriones Yes, you do. "$af\in V$" means _exactly_ "$af$ is an odd function in $C^1_{[-10,10]}$". How would you check that that is true of you didn't use the definition of an odd function? Same for "$f+g\in V$".